# Latin character conversion

Tags: permalinks, links, multi-language, migration

I'm managing a wordpress blog in Spanish for the first time and I'm currently migrating servers (e.g server A and B). The problem is that even though the file names are correctly sanitized or escaped in  server A, the file names are converted; for instance NIÑOS -> NIÃOS.

As a result, links in server B are broken. So, I'd like to know, is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which files, uploads? How are you transferring them? In which context precisely issue happens and which sanitizing functions cause it?

Comment: The transfers are done via FTP to retrieve the files. By sanitation is that permalinks don't display special characters.  On server A, I just noticed that even though file names are converted as described, links do work. The file structure and database are the same, but I think the difference  might be either in server A's configuration or in a WP configuration file.

Comment: Well, I ended up replacing the file names with a batch renamer and now links work again. I do wonder why the character conversion happens though.

Answer (score 0):

A fast way on Windows is the tool [DUK](http://forum.mysqldumper.de/dsb-s-umlaut-korrektur-duk-t2406.html). Edit and copy the config-file `dsbs-wrapper.php`  to new server, the wp install and run the tool, the exe. It will check the database and will correction the strings.